# Laravel error message return not work

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.3
i can't find solution how to echo error message i try all methods flash-> or session no luck!..

Middleware --> CheckStatus.php

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        //If the status is not approved redirect to login
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->roles != '2'){
            Auth::logout();

            return redirect('/login')->withErrors('email', 'Your error text');
        }
        return $response;
    }
```

Routes

```
Route::post('/login', [
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@login',
    'middleware' => 'checkstatus',
]);
```

Login.blade

```
@if ($errors->has('email'))
<span class="help-block">
   <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
</span>
@endif
@if (count($errors))
<ul>
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
@endif
```

i try

```
return redirect('/login')->withErrors('email', 'Your error text');
return redirect('/login')->withErrors(['email', 'Your error text']);
return redirect('/login')->with('email', 'Your error text');
```

And i try

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {});
```

My Kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckStatus::class,

    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\SetSiteLanguage::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

i can't get the error message.... any help .
**Thank you for your time!**

Comment: I don't understand. Where do you want to get an error message? And which error message do you mean? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Do not add your middleware in the `$middleware` array. Because everything inside `$middleware` will load first. So by the time your `CheckStatus` middleware loads, Laravel Session has not been loaded yet.

In `Kernel.php`

So please add your middleware in the `$routeMiddleware` array like this:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...

    'CheckStatus' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckStatus::class,
]
```

Then wrap all your routes which needs Status checking inside `CheckStatus` Middleware route group.

Ex.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['CheckStatus']], function () {
    ...
});
```

Then change the Middleware like so:

`return redirect('/login')->withErrors(['email' => 'Your error text']);`

Please try this, Hope it helps.

Comment: this method not work when i put 'CheckStatus' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckStatus::class, to $routeMiddleware function handle  not work